# Should I use a phrasal verb here or just a verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is there any rule for when to use and when not to use phrasal verbs?

E.g.,

> A1) Humans tend to pass information to others.
> A2) Humans tend to pass on information to others.

> B1) He drank the glass of juice.
> B2) He drank up the glass of juice.

Comment: There is no rule for when to use a phrasal verb. You just have to learn them (at least the most common ones) and how they might change the meaning of a phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be at least ***one*** preposition between ***to pass*** and the syntactic "object" (who- or whatever something was passed ***to***). But as with many other contexts, people often include an extra *but superfluous* preposition (something was *passed **on to**, **across to*** or ***over to** someone*).

Often it makes no difference whether these "optional" prepositions are present or not. But if it ***is*** significant, by far the most common difference is that the version with the [extra] preposition is more ***emphatic***. Hence most people in most contexts would agree that *Drink this **up*** (or *Drink this **down***, both are fine) are more emphatic than plain ***Drink this***. Specifically, ***Drink this up|down*** implies ***...all of it***, where the shorter version might simply imply ***have a taste / mouthful of this** (but you don't need to drink it all if you don't like it)*.